# How can I show only resources that are published in the future (Modx)?

Tags: modx

How can I show only resources that are published today and in the future?

Something like:

```
[[!getResources? 
&parents=`5` 
&where=`publishedon => [[dateToday?]]`
&tpl=`calendar` 
&includeContent=`1`]]
```

dateToday snippet:

```
<?php
return date("Y-m-d");
```

I would like to know how to write this statement in the correct way:

```
 &where=`publishedon => [[dateToday?]]`
```

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution:

```
&where=`{"publishedon:>":[[!stringToTime? &input=`0 days`]]}`
```